# NPM License Checker remove version

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I used the npm license checker from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-checker

The license-format.json for the customPath looks:

```
{
 "name": "",
 "version": false,
 "description": "",
 "licenses": false,
 "copyright": "",
 "licenseFile": false,
 "licenseText": false,
 "licenseModified": false,
 "path": false
}
```

When I execute

```
 npx license-checker --production --customPath license-format.json -json
```

I get the following json object:

```
 ...

 "zone.js@0.10.3": {
     "licenses": "MIT",
     "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular",
     "publisher": "Brian Ford",
     "name": "zone.js",
     "description": "Zones for JavaScript",
     "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2010-2020 Google LLC. http://angular.io/license"
  }
 ...
```

Although I removed the version in the license-format.json, the version 0.10.3 is still available near the package "zone.js@0.10.3". How can I remove the version behind the @ ?

Answer (score 0):

you can run this script:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const SEMVER_REGEX =  /@(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?/gm;

function removeVersionNumber(filePath) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
    const newValue = data.replace(SEMVER_REGEX, '');
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, newValue, 'utf-8');
    console.log('Removed license numbers');
}

removeVersionNumber(FILE_PATH);
```